# Python: How to connect to a server database?

Tags: python, sql, database, client

Which modules would you recommand for connecting a SQL database on the server and how to install and use them?

I'm developing with Python and PyQt5 an application which needs results from a server database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose it depends on what database you're looking to use. If you're using mysql you might want to check out https://github.com/PyMySQL . I have been using it and seems to be working out quite nicely.